# Office 365 Online Sync, Can't find user

Tags: powershell, automation, office365

I'm pretty new to powershell (2 months experience) and i'm creating my own scripts to automate some tasks.

Now i'm working on a usercreation script. Everything works fine until I arrive at the office365 part.

```
<Creating AD user based on template and filled info>
<Creating Exchange emailbox>
...
#Retrieving email to specify user
$email = (Get-ADUser $initials -Properties mail).mail

#Remoting into server that has Azure AD Sync installed and forcing sync
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <servername> -ScriptBlock {Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta} -Credential $AdminCredentials

#Waiting until sync is done, 30 seconds for testing purposes, can be lowered after some testing 
Write-host "Waiting untill sync is done"
Start-Sleep -s 30

#Connecting to office365
Connect-MsolService -Credential $OfficeCredentials

#Creating Licence withouth exchange
$NoExchange = New-MsolLicenseOptions -AccountSkuId syndication-account:O365_BUSINESS_PREMIUM -DisabledPlans "EXCHANGE_S_STANDARD"

#applying licence to user
Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $email -LicenseOptions $NoExchange
```

Now this last part is where I get the following error:

```
Set-MsolUserLicense : User Not Found.  User: .
At <path>\UserCreation.ps1:145 char:1
+ Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $email -LicenseOptions $NoExchange
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Set-MsolUserLicense], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.UserNotFoundException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.SetUserLicense
```

Meaning the user doesn't exist in Office 365 even tho I forced synced and issued a wait 30seconds (just to be sure its synced up)

If I try to find the user after the script returns this error I CAN find it ...

```
Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $email
```

I have tried upping the wait time to 60s but that doesn't seem to make any diffrence.
Do I have to "restart" the script or something to find the user or is there any other way I can go about this ?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to restart the script or do anything fancy at all, just increase the `Sleep` interval or check if the `Start-ADSyncSyncCycle` has a `-Wait` parameter (which it should not) or try writing something like:

```
While ((Get-ADSyncConnectorRunStatus).Runstate -eq "Busy") {
    Start-Sleep 10
}
```

Comment: So the fact that right when my script gave that error I went and looked and the user was avaible in office365 was pure coincidence ? (happened 3 times as of now)

Comment: So after you can find it, what happens if you run the command again? does it work? have you tried setting `sleep` to 2-3-5 minutes and see how that goes?

Comment: While trying this I just found out about an error in my licensingoption, I'l try fixing that first and come back to this issue :)

Comment: Ok i've tried setting the sleep to 90 seconds and got adding a normal license working now. Maybe I jumped the gun to quick on this one ..

I do have another issue now with my licenseoptions ...

Comment: in this case mark this answer as an answer and create a new question ;) @FroggyFreshh